# requests to https://test.salesforce.com/ are failing on ios 9

Tags: httprequest, ios, ssl, sslexception

With iOS 9's improved security we are not able to connect to https://test.salesforce.com

We get

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

which based on SecureTransport.h is related to a handshake failure

```
errSSLPeerHandshakeFail     = -9824,    /* handshake failure */
```

We can disable security and still connect (using NSAllowsArbitraryLoads) but we would prefer to use the new more secure ios features.

We tried making an exception just for Salesforce but still get same error

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
            <key>salesforce.com</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                    <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
            </dict>
    </dict>
```